# Correct usage of SQLAlchemy sessions

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using raw SQLAlchemy in a Flask app and used to face a lot of troubles using SQLAlchemy sessions. I used to get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR frequently mentioning that the last session was not closed properly or a rollback error. After identifying these issues I made modifications to my code and so far it is working great for me. But still, I get the error at times especially when my API breaks before the response. I want to know what will be the best way to use these sessions so that the `commit()`, `rollback()`, `close()`, etc. happen at the right time and it is generalized for all the APIs. I know that Flask-SQLAlchemy is capable of handling this automatically but I want to stick to raw SQLAlchemy.

So far the best working code for me has been -

```py
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker(bind = mysql_engine())
db_session = Session()

@app.route('/get-score', methods=['POST'])
def handle_route1():

    ...

    row = db_session.query(DB_Model_1) \
        .filter(DB_Model_1.user_id == user_id) \
        .all()

    row = row[0] if row else None
    if not row:
        db_session.close()
        return {}

    db_session.close()

    return {
        'userId': row.user_id,
        'score' : row.score
    }

@app.route('/insert-score', methods=['POST'])
def handle_route2():

    ...

@app.route('/update-score', methods=['POST'])
def handle_route3():

    ...

@app.route('/delete-score', methods=['POST'])
def handle_route3():

    ...
```

I am taking care of `GET`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` in all the different routes and I am looking for a way to handle these transactions as efficiently as possible to avoid breaking the connection to the database due to any error in API.

One way is to use **try-except** blocks but I believe there must be a better way than mentioning try-except blocks in every route individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that most elegant way is by using context manager with session / transaction scope:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def transaction_scope(session, close_at_exit=False):
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        if close_at_exit:
            session.close()
```

You can use it in two different way:

1.

```py
@app.route('/get-score', methods=['POST'])
def handle_route1():
    with Session() as session:
        with transaction_scope(session):
            ...
            row = session.query(DB_Model_1) \
              .filter(DB_Model_1.user_id == user_id) \
              .all()
            row = row[0] if row else None
        if not row:
           return {}
        return {
           'userId': row.user_id,
           'score' : row.score
        }
```

2. 

```py
@app.route('/get-score', methods=['POST'])
def handle_route1():
    session = Session()
    with transaction_scope(session, close_at_exit=True):
       ...
       row = session.query(DB_Model_1) \
          .filter(DB_Model_1.user_id == user_id) \
          .all()
       row = row[0] if row else None
       if not row:
          return {}
       return {
          'userId': row.user_id,
          'score' : row.score
       }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this completely since we are still using `db_session` for the SQLAlchemy query. Any explanation or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: When using `session.add()` in 1st way, it throws a `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError` and using `db_session.add()` neither throws an error nor adds a record to the database. 2nd way works while adding a new record for the first time but second API hit gives 500 error `MySQL server has gone away`

Comment: Please note I am not explicitly closing or using rollback sessions within the API function but instead suppose that the context manager should look after it

Comment: You should not use `db_session` that is created outside endpoint anymore. I have corrected my solution, there should be only `session`

Comment: Tried that, gives me `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError` error for the 1st way. Any idea on this or else I shall debug it?

Comment: Could you provide a traceback of an error. When is it raised?

Comment: I have changed a little bit my solution (made row attributes access within session scope).Try it please @AmitPathak

Comment: I think it is working, although need to do some tests for confirmation. After which I will mark it as accepted, have already upvoted your answer, thanks : )

Comment: @AmitPathak ok, give a feedback whether solution works for you

Comment: Using the first way looks cleaner to me. The code is working as expected, thank you for letting me get rid of handling those tedious sessions!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to read [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) part of the SQLAlchemy documentation.

But tl:dr you can use python context manager to control the scope of the session:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session.begin() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
```

Comment: During 2nd successive run, it throws `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: MySQL server has gone away`